# How to reindex pandas series from integer index to datetime

Tags: pandas, indexing, series, statsmodels

For statistical analysis, I have created an autoregression model using the statsmodels package and I have a useable model, however when I create a prediction, it is returned with an integer index instead of the initial DateTimeIndex. Here's the code

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg

model_h = AutoReg(train, lags = lag, missing = 'drop').fit()
predictions = model_h.model.predict(model_h.params, start = '2023-02-13 00:00:00', 
                                    end= '2023-02-13 12:00:00')
```

train is a Dataframe with a Datetimeindex that only contains the training data.

I have tried reindexing with an index created using pd.Daterange and others but the returned series is emptpy, any heads up is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you want `.set_index()` instead of `.reindex()`, is that it? `.reindex()` is like a join operation, but `.set_index()` just replaces the index.